# How we can implement SSO and MSLogin authentication on single azure application using Enterprise application and App Registration

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We need help in implementation of MS Login and SSO together on same azure application and we are facing below challenges.

Currently we have implemented MSLogin and SSO authentication with independent Azure application and it is working as expected.

But now customer is expecting that instead of configuring the MSLogin and SSO authentication setting independently in azure for two application can we have it with one azure application only.

Based on above scenario I have following question:

1. Can we implement MSLogin and SSO authentication together? If any lead would be highly appreciated.
2. Currently I have some partial implementation of the above approach but facing challenge with redirect URL.
   Issue: If I configure the same application for MSLogin & SSO authentication then
3. For MSLogin its mandatory for us to provide the redirect URL and if we don’t pass it then MSLogin authentication not working.
4. If we pass this redirect url then the reply URL which we have set for SSO is not getting triggered and always redirecting to MSLogin redirect URL only through azure cloud (don’t have any control).

Any help on above issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

•   The redirect URL option is featured with those apps who have custom app registrations other than that of Azure apps specified in the gallery for whom the redirect URL is already configured inbuilt to be of Azure sign out page.

•   That’s why, the sign out URL is of utmost importance in enterprise applications from where the Identity signing out of that platform is confirmed. Thus, you can check the following method of using a state parameter while configuring the redirect URLs might be useful.

•   Create a "shared" redirect URI per application to process the security tokens you receive from the authorization endpoint.

•   Your application can send application-specific parameters (such as subdomain URL where the user originated or anything like branding information) in the state parameter. When using a state parameter, guard against CSRF protection as specified in section 10.12 of RFC 6749).

•   The application-specific parameters will include all the information needed for the application to render the correct experience for the user, that is, construct the appropriate application state. The Azure AD authorization endpoint strips HTML from the state parameter so make sure you are not passing HTML content in this parameter.

•   When Azure AD sends a response to the "shared" redirect URI, it will send the state parameter back to the application.

•   The application can then use the value in the state parameter to determine which URL to further send the user to. Make sure you validate for CSRF protection.

•   Also, the client must protect these parameters by encrypting the state or verifying it by some means as you are using a personal Microsoft login for authentication purposes which means personal Microsoft accounts will be able to access the application configured in Azure AD, so please validate the domain name in the redirect URI against the token.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-microsoft